# Difference in hash rates between Bitcoins and Litecoins calculation

Tags: litecoin

I recently discovered the Hash rate of my graphic card is different with Bitcoins than Litecoins. I understand this is due to the difference in the algorithm. Bitcoin has a double sha256 instead of Litecoins.

If I have a Miner of 1THash/s at Bitcoins what will be the average hash rate I get on calculating the Litecoins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using general purpose mining hardware (i.e. CPU, GPU) then it really depends on lots of factors, not only hardware, but also mining software and even its configuration.

For details on mining hardware you can check the tables for [Bitcoin](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison) and [Litecoin](https://litecoin.info/Mining_hardware_comparison).

But with the inevitable introduction of ASIC miners (already for Bitcoin, and soon for Litecoin) the question is actually irrelevant.

ASIC miners can only work with the hashing function for which they were designed.
So a Bitcoin ASIC miner (SHA256) cannot mine Litecoin (scrypt) at all, and vice-versa.